# Construct an NFA wherein the first symbol of only appears once

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Given the language
$$
L= \{w \in \{a,b,c,d\}^* \mid \text{the first symbol of $w$ appears only once in $w$}\}
$$

[This is the answer I came up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xeik.png) and I'm not entirely sure if this is the right way to construct NFAs because the concept of having multiple next states is still confusing to me, and I don't know when a state can have more than one next state. Is there a formula of some sorts or is it really all down to just knowing what the next states are?

Comment: Yes, that works, assuming that the alphabet is $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and not $\{a,b,c\}$ as in your question. You could get rid of $q_5$ by making $q_1,q_2,q_3$, and $q_4$ acceptor states, and then you could get rid of $q_6,q_7,q_8$, and $q_9$ by moving their loops back to $q_1,q_2,q_3$, and $q_4$, respectively.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake I forgot to type in d on the alphabet. If _q5_ were to be removed, it is still possible to convert it to an equivalent DFA?

Comment: Yes, the usual algorithm for converting an NFA to a DFA always works.

Answer (score 1):

Following Brian M. Scott's comment, you actually get directly the following deterministic incomplete automaton:

$\hskip 90pt$ [image]

If you want to get a deterministic complete automaton, just add one state as follows:

$\hskip 80pt$ [image]